# Ubuntu 18.04 Nautilus copy image instead of path

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, filemanager, paste, copy-and-paste

I am used to simply COPY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) an image file from the file manager and past it into a document (Slack, Google Docs etc), this is standard feature on Windows and macOS.

However on Ubuntu 18.04 and Nautilus (File 3.26.4) it copies a path like this: `/home/petrvecera/Pictures/Wallpapers/tumblr_nfet2oaZ3P1tbxz68o1_1280.jpg` instead of the file...

**How to copy image file and not the path?**

I know that I can use drag and drop but that is not as effective as simple copy and is pain to re-arrange windows. I have found this plugin https://www.maketecheasier.com/copy-paste-images-clipboard-nautilus/ however it just adds "feature" into the menu.

Comment: I think the app you paste the data to should be responsible, not Nautilus. If Nautilus would copy the image contents, what would happen when you paste into a text editor ? LibreOffice for example pastes the content, not the path.

Comment: @RoVo you are right it's possible that it's not an issue with the Nautilus it-self but the app needs to implement it. I was used to this on macOS mostly where it works for me almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

what I do, and I know this may seem slow but it's the "get it done approach", is I open the image in [www.photopea.com](https://www.photopea.com/) or a locally installed editing app such as pinta or gimp.

Pinta : [pinta](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pinta) [image: Install pinta]

Gimp : [gimp](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gimp) [image: Install gimp]

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then I have it ready to paste as an image.

the plugin you mention is of 2016 and must have broken down in ubuntu 18+. you might have to signal a bug then wait for a new verison to come out or for another plugin to come out.

Xclip could get you what you wish in the meantime in a terminal-based approach :

[xclip](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xclip) [image: Install xclip]

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i example.png
```

NOTE: Some research shows that you need xclip from SVN revision 81 (from April 2010) or later to have the required `-t` option. Or apply [the patches](http://sourceforge.net/p/xclip/patches/4/) yourself.

sources :

- [How to copy an image to the clipboard from a file using command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759651/how-to-copy-an-image-to-the-clipboard-from-a-file-using-command-line)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145131/copy-image-from-clipboard-to-file

Comment: How would that be better than the plugin OP mentions?

Comment: as he sais it fixes the issue with precise positioning you get with drag and drop, to be able to type "Ctrl"+"V" where the cursor is. also you won't get weird conversions. you'll get the actual pixels that you can then resize to suit your needs.

Comment: But if you do the [right click -> Copy image action](https://www.maketecheasier.com/copy-paste-images-clipboard-nautilus/) it will be the same but faster

Comment: right click copy image with what nautilus? or gimp? in the first case you can't and in the second no it's not. keyboard is much faster.

Comment: Why do you think that the plugin is broken. OP even says that *it just adds "feature" into the menu*, so it seems working for him. But that is not what OP wants. Instead, you answer with even more complicated options ...

Comment: well I followed the link and the screenshots clearly show that that plugin was meant to add a "copy paste images" menu option. that he does not have this menu option or it's sub-options is indicative of a fault in the pugin's expected behavior. https://www.maketecheasier.com/copy-paste-images-clipboard-nautilus/

Comment: Thanks @tatsu for your help. But I was looking for a solution which would be super fast and boost my productivity.

Comment: I know I'm looking for the same so I'd like to be notified as well. For the record I tried the plugin as well. I get no new menus at all. I really think it's impossible for a plugin devellopped for the Unity desktop and for xorg to work out of the box on gnome-ubuntu-desktop and on Wayland. I really think our best bet here is for someone to make a new plugin from scratch.

Comment: It's 2023 and I can't believe there is still no solution for this! The plugin mentioned would do the job if it were being maintained, but alas, it's not...

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023, the plugin that would be the ideal solution doesn't seem to work (https://github.com/atareao/nautilus-copypaste-images/issues/2) on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, I cannot even install it from the repo.

<s>The fastest/easiest solution that I have found, is to drag the image from Nautilus to Firefox (or any other browser I guess would work) and just right-click and copy from there.</s>

**UPDATE**
The XnView MP image viewer does this. When you enter viewer mode (not thumbnails) you right-click and select "Copy" it copies the image.