# Digikam: Copy and Paste images

Tags: nautilus, copy-and-paste, digikam

I would like to copy some images from Digikam to Nautilus.

Somehow I prefer ctrl-c and ctrl-v to drag+drop.

The context-menu in Nautilus is empty, although I selected and copied some files in Digikam.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find the alternative posted meets your needs?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio drag+drop works, but I prefer copy+paste

Comment: Ok. Just to double check if I understood it... is the workaround you posted "ctrl-c + ctrl-v"-type?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I usually have one window open in full screen mode. I switch between windows fluently by alt+tab. So the light-table approach is more "full screen mode" than drag+drop. I really don't understand why copy+paste does not work. Feels like in stone-age.

Comment: I provided an explanation to your question.
Pro: now you know why that doesn't work (and the situation is not *that much* of a stone age).
Con: there is (apparently) no simple way to make it work as of now. You could write your own patch, I guess ;-)

Comment: Did you find the answer appropriate? (even if not what you have liked to hear...)

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio in your answer you say that copying several images is not possible? Is it impossible? What is missing to get this solved? I don't think software is missing. It is missing an agreement (standard/spec).

Comment: I think (as per my experience and wording in official documentation) that *with Eye of Gnome* it is not possible to copy more than one **image** at a time. With Digikam you *can* do that.
In any of these two cases, you get **images** in the clipboard, not **files**.
What is missing? I guess you can view it in many ways. For instance, there was a (now outdated) extension to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What am I doing wrong?**

Nothing.
When you copy an image or several images from Digikam to the clipboard with Ctrl-C, they are just that, images, not image files.
You could try [copying from other sources like Eye of Gnome](https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/copy-paste.html.en) `eog` (I could only copy one image at a time, I don't think it's possible to copy several at a time), to further demonstrate the same behaviour.

Then you can paste the *images*, e.g., in LibreOffice Impress.
But you cannot paste the image files in Nautilus, since that is not in the clipboard.
There is an extension for Nautilus to do that, [nautilus-copypaste-images](https://github.com/atareao/nautilus-copypaste-images).
Unfortunately, it is not maintained, and it's not available for focal.
You can [check this](https://serverfault.com/questions/252333/list-all-packages-from-a-repository-in-ubuntu-debian) (once the ppa was added and after `sudo apt-get update`) [with](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/how-to-list-all-packages-in-repository.html)

```
grep ^Package /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_atareao_nautilus-extensions_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_binary-*_Packages | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u
```

You could try using [the `.deb` file](http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/nautilus-extensions/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nautilus-copypaste-images/). YMMV.

I did not find any alternative so far
(you could write your own patch, I guess ;-)).

**Related**:

1. [Ubuntu 18.04 Nautilus copy image instead of path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132689/ubuntu-18-04-nautilus-copy-image-instead-of-path)
2. http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/copy-and-paste-images-from-clipboard-in.html
3. https://www.maketecheasier.com/copy-paste-images-clipboard-nautilus/
4. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/540

---

**Non Ctrl-c + Ctrl-v alternative**:

1. Open Digikam and Nautilus.
2. Arrange them in a side-by-side view (with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>).
3. Select in Digikam the files I want to copy (6 images, see screenshot).
4. Drag to Nautilus.

It works out-of-the-box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I prefer copy+paste to drag+drop.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around: Put the selected files onto the "Light Table".

There you can export them to a local directory.

Wow ... feels a bit like in the stone-age of usability.